# Do I need to renew my Mac Developer Program enrolment to continue signing OSX apps?

Tags: macos, code-signing, gatekeeper

A company I know has an Apple developer account and was enrolled on the Mac Developer Program in order to be able to sign apps (not for the Mac App Store, but for Gatekeeper validation purposes).

However, this enrolment expired a couple of months ago, but apparently they're still able to sign apps (the certificates only expire 3.5 years from now) and no problems have been reported by users installing/running these apps.

Is it necessary for some reason to renew the Mac Developer Program before the certificates expire? Is there any specific reason why this would be necessary, or could they potentially continue signing (non Mac App Store) apps and only renew the enrolment when the certificates are about to expire?